# Much weaker condition for Kakeya sets over finite fields

Tags: co.combinatorics, additive-combinatorics

What is the minimum size of a subset $S \subseteq \mathbb{F}_p^n$ such that for all directions $a \in \mathbb{F}_p^n$, there is a line in direction $a$ that intersects $S$ in at least $C$ points?

If $C = p$ this is exactly the finite field Kakeya problem, and we know $|S| \ge C_n p^n$ by the proof of Dvir in [On the size of Kakeya sets in finite fields](https://arxiv.org/abs/0803.2336). However, I am curious what bounds we can show if e.g. $C$ is much smaller than $p$, eg. $C = \log^{O(1)}(pn)$.

I believe by random sampling, one can show an upper bound of something like $\lvert S\rvert \le p^{(1-1/C)n}$, which is trivial for $C = \log^{O(1)}(pn)$. A lower bound of $\lvert S\rvert \ge p^{(n-1)/2}$ is also clear, because the points in $S$ determine at most $\lvert S\rvert^2$ lines.

Also, in Dvir's paper, he also handles the case where $C = p^{1-\epsilon}$, but I am asking for even much smaller values of $C$.
So is the truth closer to $p^{n/2}$ or $p^n$?

Comment: The paper of Dvir gets a bound for any $C$ - the $C=p^{1-\epsilon}$ is just for getting a lower bound of size $p^{n (1-\epsilon)}$ - but it's of size a bit less than $C^n$, so it's worse than the points determine lines lower bound for $C < \sqrt{p}$.

Answer (score 9):

As claimed in equation (2) of this recent paper

*Dhar, Manik; Dvir, Zeev; Lund, Ben*, Simple proofs for Furstenberg sets over finite fields,  [ZBL07471814](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:07471814) [[arXiv]](https://arxiv.org/abs/1909.03180).

one can get a lower bound of $2^{-n} C^n$ by adapting the arguments from

*Bukh, Boris; Chao, Ting-Wei*, Sharp density bounds on the finite field Kakeya problem,  [ZBL07471810](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:07471810). [[arXiv]](https://arxiv.org/abs/2108.00074)

For $C=p$ the bound is tight up to a factor of $2$.  I don't know what to conjecture for other values of $C$.

EDIT: for $C=2$ I would imagine by the usual union bound argument that a random set of cardinality $p^{n/2} n^{10} \log^{10} p$ (say) should work to give a upper bound, though I haven't checked this carefully. So maybe the truth is something like $p^{n/2} C^{n/2}$ up to lower order terms?

Comment: Your guess at the end suggests that one can achieve $C=3$ with a set of size $p^{ n (1/2 +o(1))}$.  Here's an argument that this might not be possible: If this occurs, then the probability that two random points in the set are colinear with a third point in the set is at least $p^{- o(n)}$. This should imply the set is highly additively structured. But highly additively structured sets are the least likely to contain two points on a line in an arbitrary direction.

Comment: Hmm, good point, my initial guess was too naive and there does seem to be some sort of discontinuity when going from $C=2$ to $C=3$.  Probably one has to work harder at trying all kinds of constructions before arriving at a tentative prediction (but then again, there was no consensus on what to conjecture for cap sets until Dvir's breakthrough).

Comment: Thanks for the answers! And yes, as mentioned in the original post, random sampling (or other constructions) do achieve an upper bound of $p^{(1-1/C)n}$ up to polynomial factors in $p, n$, which is $p^{n/2}$ for $C = 2$.